# getting a 500 internl server error with nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i have installed nginx on my ubuntu ec2 instance and im building an app using node.js, and when i go my amazon url i.e.

```
http://elastic.ip.address
```

it works fine, so its running the / file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('home');
  });
```

however when i try go to  `http://elastic.ip.address/page2:`

```
    app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('page2');

  });
```

I get the 500 internal server error, so i really don't know whats happening, this works on my localhost without running nginx, but not my ec2.

this is my nginx configuration file layout:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /home/ubuntu/project/;



        server_name  static_ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com;


        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8124/;
        }
```

Comment: I think it was trying to call another location from Nginx config, else Intially it called http://127.0.0.1:8124/, when you try to call http://elastic.ip.address/page2 it is calling http://127.0.0.1:8124//page2 "//" was the only mistake. May be silly ans ignore if you feel silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to try:

- Have a look at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and see if you can get some better information about what's going wrong.
- Make sure that the user that nginx is running as has read permissions to `/home/ubuntu/project/`.